# Excel FuzzyLookup: Similarity Check works fine, but wrong values in cells of other columns

Tags: excel, lookup, fuzzy

I am using the Excel FuzzyLookup Add-In. I have two tables with each 30 columns and >100.000 rows. I conduct the similarity check only for one column of each table. This works fine. However, through the similarity check, I am adding the other columns automatically (which is intended and needed). I find that the entries of the cells in each column do not always match.

For instance:
Table 1

| Name | Price | Share (%) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 3 | 5 |
| Mariah | 1 | 3.5 |
| Sarah | 2 | 10 |

Table 2

| Entity | Portfolio | Industry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 3000 | Chemical |
| Maria | 1000 | Auto |
| Sarah | 2000 | Clothes |

Similarity Check

| Name | Portfolio | Industry | Price | Share (%) | Entity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Peter | 3000 | Chemical | 3 | 9999999 | Peter |
| Maria | 1000 | Auto | 1 | 3.5 | Mariah |

Here I have shown that the Share for Peter is now depicted as 9999999.

(Please note this is a very simplified example.)

Help is kindly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Maria